# HTML form select onchange chang another select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 selects. The first one defines if the customer will be billed with invoice or not. If yes then onchange to invoice type 1 or 2 the second select taxes changes automaticly to apply 19% taxes. If I change back to no invoice it switch to tax free.

How can I accomplish this?

```
<select id="invoice">
  <option value="no" selected>no invoice</option>
  <option value="invoice-type-1">invoice type 1</option>
  <option value="invoice-type-2">invoice type 2</option>
</select>

<select id="taxes">
  <option value="0"> tax free</option>
  <option value="19"> apply 19%</option>

</select>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEUwg/344/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a simple jquery. On invoice change check value and switch the other depending on which value you have.

```
$('#invoice').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='no')
        $('#taxes').val('0');
    else
        $('#taxes').val('19');
});
```

Jsfiddle [--DEMO--](http://jsfiddle.net/63hea0k0/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#invoice").change(function(){
    if($(this).val().indexOf("invoice") !== -1) {
        $("#taxes").val(19);
    } else {
        $("#taxes").val(0);
    }
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QEUwg/345/